# The overlap of two Gaussian states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics, wick-theorem

According to e.g. Serafini (Quantum Continuous Variables), the Hilbert-Schmidt product ('overlap') of two multimode Gaussian states $\rho_1,\rho_2$ is

$$\text{Tr}[\rho_1\rho_2]=|\langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle|^2=\frac{2^n}{\sqrt{\text{Det}(\sigma_1+\sigma_2)}}e^{(r_1-r_2)^T(\sigma_1+\sigma_2)^{-1}(r_1-r_2)},$$

where $r_{1,2}$ are the displacements in phase space and $\sigma_1,\sigma_2$ the covariance matrices.

My question: is there a similar formula for $\langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle$ itself, retaining information on their relative phase?

Answer (score 4):

There cannot be such an expression because the covariance matrix and displacement don't contain the relative phase information. This is easy to see, since they are computed from the reduced density matrix (which does not depend on the phase of the state).

A way around this can be to include a third reference state and $\vert\chi\rangle$ and consider the overlap
$$
\langle \psi_1|\psi_2\rangle\langle\psi_2\vert\chi\rangle\langle\chi\vert\psi_1\rangle
$$
which only depends on the density matrices, and is thus a function of the covariance matrices & displacement.

Note, however, that also this quantity is (necessarily!) invariant under changing phases, so whether it gives you the desired information depends on the scenario you consider.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm a bit confused because the density matrix should contain all relevant information and also for the total one $\rho=\frac{1}{N}\sum_i |\psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_i|$? What is confusing me more is now the difference between states $|-\alpha>$ and $exp(i\pi)*|\alpha>$, which should both be $|\alpha>$ rotated over $\pi$, but for the first one the density matrix changes as well, and for the second phasefactor it doesn't.

Comment: What I'm after in the end is calculating the total von Neumann entropy, as you have given me already the very useful answer in https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/498790/25292 . Now, if the DMs of the individual Gaussians, and hence the covariance matrices and displacement, loose the phase information; I would expect that if I'm working with a stochastic unraveling (quantum trajectories), there should be phase symmetry in the ensemble steady state and hence I can in retrospect assign a phase to each Gaussian from a uniform $[0,2\pi]$ distribution?

Comment: Well, in fact the Hamiltonian explicitly breaks the $U(1)$ symmetry in each of the modes, so I know this affects the phase that is reflected in DM and displacement (my $|-\alpha>$ example), but I've assumed now this doesn't affect these additional phasefactors?

Comment: Ok, I think now that this phasefactor should be irrelevant for all practical purposes, see e.g. the situation on the link above

Comment: You can compute the von Neumann entropy directly from the covariance matrix, no need for all this.  Why don't you post a question how to compute the vN entropy from the CM?

Comment: To my understanding, the CM is only really useful within a single gaussian state, but even if they are individually all pure, a mixture of them (which is not Gaussian anymore) will have a finite entropy. Your answer starting from the overlap elements (which can be calculated by the CMs indeed) was really useful to get there, was there a shortcut?

Comment: The entropy of a single (mixed) Gaussian state is a property of its CM.  The entropy of what do you want to compute?

Comment: Say, only in terms of coherent states for simplicity, $|1\rangle\langle 1|+|2i\rangle\langle 2i|$ is a sum of two Gaussians, but it is not Gaussian itself

Comment: I see.  Well, in that case indeed what you would need is ways of defining phases of triples.  (For a pair of states, the phase is indeed irrelevant for the entropy.)

Comment: For me, the problem is solved in practice by the coherent approximation I describe below. For the sake of the question here, your response is perhaps more complete though. I don't see that "there cannot be such an expression because the covariance matrix and displacement don't contain the relative phase information" though, I think the phase information must be somewhere in there (otherwise it couldn't come out when looking at triples).

Comment: If you could expand on this to prove that displacement and covariance matrix don't set the relative phase (or give a counterexample), I'll take this as accepted answer. If not, I still consider this question as open, because I could certainly imagine a formula (although possibly complicated) be derived in a similar way to coherent states, but with also some squeezing operators present (which in turn contain the same information as the covariance matrix).

Comment: @Wouter Both are derived from the density matrix.  The density matrix does not carry information about relative phases.  That's it. No more to explain, as far as I can see. Or would you believe a formula with the same information?

Comment: If the density matrices of all Gaussians are known, the total entropy is known. If the total entropy is known, and it depends on the relative phases, that means the this phase information can come from no other place than the density matrices? .

Apart from that, ref. https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.41.4625. Explicitly claims "Equations (2.34)—(2.40) show that variances can be described very conveniently by the squeeze matrix z" as well as (eq. 2.24) how this squeeze matrix, together with the displacement, defines the wavefunction.

Comment: You don't get it. You can re-define the phases of every $|\psi_n\rangle$. This allows you to change *some* of the phases in the overlap matrix, namely $N$ of them. However, there are about $N^2/2$ phases in the overlap matrix. Those matter for the entropy.  That's what the whole last discussion was about. Of course the entropy of a mixture does not change under $|psi_n\rangle\to e^{i\phi_n}|\psi_n\rangle$.

Comment: Sure, but I think this time you're not getting my point. The overlap phases emerge only as a result from the states $|\psi_n\rangle,|\psi_m\rangle$. And everything in $|\psi_n\rangle$ wavevectors is either fixed by knowing $|\psi_n\rangle\langle\psi_n|$ or can be chosen. Even in your example, the two different $|\psi_3\rangle$'s have different off-diagonal elements in their density matrices.

Comment: That is simply not true.  If they would emerge from there, you could make them all positive by gauge transformations.  This is not true generally.  You would have to check if it holds for displaced coherent states from the formula below.  But this is not obvious - you would have to see that you can choose phases which make all positive. Note that this is not the same as the phase of the $\alpha$ in the coherent state!

Comment: Perhaps I should have clarified that the Gaussians under consideration are pure states, in this case, there is (up to the phasefactor) a one-to-one correspondence between density matrices and wavevectors? and the inner product of those wavevectors is the overlap element? I'm not sure what it is precisely that you say is not true. I'm not (no longer, at least) claiming all phasefactors can be transformed away; but I just don't see a fundamental reason why they cannot be expressed in terms of the covariance matrix elements and displacements (as is the case for coherent states).

Comment: The entropy of the mixture can be expressed in terms of covariance matrices, but the overlap matrix of the states can't.

Comment: Why can't they? Which flaw do I make in the reasoning of my last comment? In short: DMs<->wavefunctions<->overlap elements , this is very basic reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

If the Gaussians are not too far from coherent states, a useful approximation is obtained by calculating the phasefactors of a coherent state, for which analytical formulas do exist (this comes down to taking into accound the displacement but not the squeezing/covariance matrix). According to e.g. the book Quantum Noise (Gardiner-Zoller), the scalar product of two single-mode coherent states is

$$\langle\alpha|\beta\rangle=\exp(\alpha^*\beta-\frac{1}{2}|\alpha|^2-\frac{1}{2}|\beta|^2),$$

from which one immediately gets

$$\frac{\langle\alpha|\beta\rangle}{|\langle\alpha|\beta\rangle|}=\exp(\frac{\alpha^*\beta-\beta^*\alpha}{2})$$ for the phasefactor.

As a coherent state factorizes over all modes, the overall phasefactor under this approximation is the product of the phasefactors over these individual modes.